# Azure WebApp How to Get a Useful 500 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I searched previous questions, first, but could not find anything that solved my issue. I have a Web App project that works fine locally, then fails with 500 after having been published. This is my first time using any of the Microsoft stack (C#, ASP.NET MVC, Azure), so bear with me.

- Visual Studio 2015 Community
- .NET 4.5 / ASP.NET 5 Web App project
- StackExchange.Redis / Fleck / React.AspNET NuGet packages

I have added the following to `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  ...
  <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<tracing>
  <traceFailedRequests />
</tracing>
</system.webServer>
```

I also turned on `detailed error messages` under the web app's settings using the Server Explorer view in Visual Studio (right-click the app's name, click settings). I also attempted to remotely debug the web app, but received an "access is denied"(["Remote debugging does not work in Express editions of Visual Studio"](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/) maybe?). So, I'll post the `web.config` from the Azure web app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
    <tracing>
      <traceFailedRequests />
    </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

One or a combination of these changes mentioned above worked in providing a more useful error screen.

If someone can come along and post an answer as to which step(s) it may have been and why, etc. I'd be glad to accept it. I don't want to post an answer, as I honestly don't know which 'fixed' it.

Comment: Do you by chance have a web.config.release in your Project? It might be using Transformations to change the customErrors value.

Comment: Nope, no web.config.release in my project

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mention **ASP.NET 5 Web App project** so this means you have a **Startup.cs** file, right?

Check in your **project.json** file if you have (if not add it) the [Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics/) package.

Then add on the `public void Configure` handler:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();            
        //other app.Uses
}
```

This is intended for local dev because it will show the detailed full error, you might want to later add it in an if:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

[Source: docs.asp.net](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/diagnostics.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [customErrors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx) element belongs under system.web

The most common error people make when first deploying to Azure or any other server is to properly set connection strings for that environment, so I would start by checking those.

Comment: From what I can gather, connection strings seem to be used to connect to SQL databases and the like. Are they used for anything else?